# Checking email using js

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email

I have a form that I created and I am trying to check the email field to make sure it's an email. And I only want for people to be able to enter @msu.edu email addresses. I have the script written out to check for the email, but it is not working, and I do not know how to make it to where only a @msu.edu can be used.

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return checkbae()" name="validation">
            <div class="form-group row" id="price">                
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First *" required >
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Last *" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="E-mail *"  required>
                </div>                
            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" align="center">
              <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">                
                <button type="submit" class="button default">SEND <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>



         </form>

   <script language="JavaScript1.2">


var testresults
function checkemail(){
var str=document.validation.emailcheck.value
var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
if (filter.test(str))
testresults=true
else{
alert("Please input a valid email address!")
testresults=false
}
return (testresults)
}
</script>

<script>
function checkbae(){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById||document.all)
return checkemail()
else
return true
}
</script>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that YOU have written the check-script? ;D

In the script you access a field `emailcheck` which does not exist in the form.

Solutions:

**Update**

Tested and working.

`function checkMail() {
    var email = document.validation.email.value.toLowerCase();
    var suffix = '@msu.edu';
    var result = email.indexOf(suffix, email.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    alert('Valid email found: ' + result);
    return result;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/du65V/

**Update 2**

Using RegEx. Also tested and working.

`function checkMail() {
    var email = document.validation.email.value.toLowerCase();
    var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@msu.edu/i;
    var result = filter.test(email);
    alert('Valid email found: ' + result);
    return result;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/du65V/1/

Comment: The wording of the question does not claim that the OP wrote it. Testing the string ends with that domain is more appropriate than testing if the string _contains_ it. The input should still be validated as an email (using filter_var).

Comment: The wording of the question implies that the OP wrote it. Yet it contains substantional errors like accessing non-existing fields and not using any semicolons at all. And thats the reason why "his" script is not working. So **IF** the OP wrote it then he would be easily able to fix it just by accessing the correct `.email.`-field instead of `.emailcheck.` But yes you are right. It would be more appropriate to do all the other checks. Nontheless it is obvious (for me) that the OP didn't write the script so I would like to leave some work to him. ;)

Comment: It's obvious to me too but "I have the below script written out" !== "I have written the below script". It might be what was meant - but it might not. If you don't at least hint that there should be server-side validation (the q is tagged php) you aren't really helping the op, especially since your suggested js solution will accept obviously invalid input such as "@msu.edu".

Comment: If he wrote the script or not isn't important at all mate. :D The question maybe tagged `php` but since he asked how to check email using JS I assume he tagged it wrong? Nontheless I provided a direct answer to his request to only allow entering emails from @msu.edu. So if you want to provide a more complex solution feel free to do so. But until then you aren't helping him much either by criticizing my answer, do you? ;)

Comment: It's "Important" because of your point 2. I commented primarily to point out the weakness of the suggested solution (existing solution accepts any email, answer accepts any string containing the domain). I don't write answers when I'm using a phone.

Comment: the code you gave me is not working. I get a syntax error message.

Comment: Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/du65V/ The syntax error was caused by using `<>` instead of `!==`. I also updated my answer above.